# assign subset of parent table to objects in R

Tags: r

I would like to iterate through a table and break it into relvant parts based on the number of visits. I have tried several things but cannot seem to get it to work.

I have included the code.

```
for(i in 1:6){
   paste("testing.visit",i,"\n",sep="") <- subset(testing,visit_no==2)
}
```

But I get the following error.

```
Error in paste("testing.visit", i, "\n", sep = "") <- subset(testing,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Thank you,

Brandon

Comment: Similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly-in-r, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590043/creating-a-series-of-vectors-from-a-vector

Answer (score 4):

Try `assign` inside the `for` loop:

```
assign(paste("testing.visit", i, "\n", sep=""),  subset(testing, visit_no==i))
```

You could also use `dlply` (`plyr` package ) to combine the subsets into a list:

```
library("plyr")
testing.visit <- dlply(testing, .(visit_no))
```