# Assign new names to dataframes and save as separate objects in R

Tags: r, save

I am performing a set of analyses in R. The flow of the analysis is reading in a dataframe (i.e. `input_dataframe`), performing a set of calculations that then result in a new, smaller dataframe (called `final_result`). A set of exact calculations is performed on 23 different files, each of which contains a dataframe.

My question is as follows: **For each file that is read in (i.e. the 23 files) I am trying to save a unique R object: How do I do so?** When I save the resulting `final_result` dataframe (using `save()` to an R object, I then cannot read all 23 objects into a new R session without having the different R objects override each other. Other suggestions (such as [Create a variable name with "paste" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510966/create-a-variable-name-with-paste-in-r)) did not work for me, since they rely on the fact that once the new variable name is assigned, you then call that new variable by its name, which I cannot do in this case.

**To Summarize/Reword:** Is there a way to save an object in R but change the name of the object for when it will be loaded later?
For example:

```
x=5
magicSave(x,file="saved_variable_1.r",to_save_as="result_1")
x=93
magicSave(x,file="saved_variable_2.r",to_save_as="result_2")
load(saved_variable_1)
load(saved_variable_2)
result_1
#returns 5
result_2
#returns 93
```

Comment: Could you be just looking for `saveRDS` ? `readRDS(...)` has to be assigned to an object, unlike `load(...)`

Comment: Does `saveRDS` allow for saving the object with my own custom name?

Comment: `saveRDS` doesn't save the name at all,  `x <- readRDS(...)` creates a variable named `x`

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't work with lists of 23 elements and save your list of 23 results as one object ?

Comment: Thats a good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `R` it's generally a good idea to actually store as a list everything that can be seen as a list. It will make everything more elegant afterwards.

First you put all your paths in a list or a vector :

```
paths <- c("C:/somewhere/file1.csv",
           "C:/somewhere/file2.csv") # etc
```

Then you read them :

```
objects <- lapply(paths,read.csv) # objects is a list of tables
```

Then you apply your transformation on each element :

```
output <- lapply(objects,transformation_function)
```

And then you can save your output (I find `saveRDS` cleaner than `save` as you know what variables you'll be inviting in your workspace when loading) :

```
saveRDS(output,"C:/somewhere/output.RDS")
```

which you will load with

```
output <- readRDS("C:/somewhere/output.RDS")
```

OR if you prefer for some reason to save as different objects:

```
output_paths <- paste0("C:/somewhere/output",seq_along(output),".csv")
Map(saveRDS,output,output_paths)
```

To load later with:

```
output <- lapply(paths, readRDS)
```

Comment: I think this is the best that is reasonably possible in R, so I am going to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=5
write.csv(x,"one_thing.csv", row.names = F)
x=93
write.csv(x,"two_thing.csv", row.names = F)
result_1 <- read.csv("one_thing.csv")
result_2 <- read.csv("two_thing.csv")

result_1
# x
# 1 5
result_2
# x
# 1 93
```

Comment: This solution will not allow for writing and reading dataframes or other complex data structures. Furthermore, it relies on the knowing the name of the object that I want to read to (i.e. `result_1 <- read.csv("one_thing.csv")` and assigning it to that object. What if I am saving 100 objects?