# R "for loop" and/or Apply to transform several variables dynamically

Tags: r, eviews

I am trying to translate/replicate into R a shorthand "for loop" technique that I would use in EViews. I'm trying to replicate a "for loop" where I would divide one time series variable by another (vectors) and save it as a new series.

As I use a common naming convention (for example GDP (real), GDPn (nominal) and GDP_P (prices), see EViews example below), I can declare the list of variables once and use changes in the suffix ("n" or "_P") to create dynamic series names and loop through the calculations I  need. My input data is national accounts expenditure series.

```
'EViews shorthand "for next" loop:

%CATS = "GDP CONS INV GOV EX IM"
 for %CATS {%cats}
   series {%cats}_P= {%cats}n / {%cats}
 next

'Which is shorthand replication of below ("series" declares a series of the subsequent name):

series GDP_P    = GDPn / GDP
series CONS_P   = CONSn / CONS
series INV_P    = INVn /  INV
series GOV_P    = GOVn / GOV
series EX_P     = EXn / EX
series IM_P     = IMn / IM
```

So far I've tried using an R for loop (which I have read is not the preferred way in R) by creating a vector of the series name and used "assign(paste" to do the calculation. An example is below but it does not work. From what I have read about the "for" command, the declared series for "i" can only be a vector of values or a vector of names with no further context:

```
cats<-c("GDP","CONS","GOV","INV","EX","IM")
for (i in cats){
  assign(paste(i, "_P",sep=""), paste(i, "n",sep="")/i)
}
```

I've also done a lot of reading into the "apply" function and derivatives, but I can't see how it works the above scenario. Any suggestions for how to do this in R is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should work like this:

```
cats<-c("GDP","CONS","GOV","INV","EX","IM")
for (i in cats){
  assign(paste(i, "_P",sep=""), get(paste(i, "n",sep=""))/get(i))
}
```

The `get` will use the strings you provide and find the vector of that name.

There's also a non-for-loop way of doing it, using the idea from one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510966/create-a-variable-name-with-paste-in-r):

```
txt<-paste0(cats, "_P <- ", cats, "n/", cats)
eval(parse(text=txt))
```

`txt` will include a list of all the lines that you would have had to type to create all your vectors manually, and then `eval(parse(text=txt))` takes each of those commands and executes them one by one.

You can of course skip the assigning of the text to `txt` -- I just wanted it to be clearer what's going on here:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0(cats, "_P <- ", cats, "n/", cats)))
```

Comment: Reconsider using [`assign()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17559390/1422451) and [`eval(parse(...))`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649979/1422451). R is a functional programming language designed for explicit assignment of objects and method calls, not string-rendered backdoor processes.

Comment: Is there a practical reason why? Other than puritanism?

Answer (score 1):

Consider working with lists especially for many similar elements. Doing so you can better manage your global environment and process data more compactly and efficiently. For you this means maintaining 3 lists of vectors instead of 18 separate named vectors (2 original sets and new 3rd set). The use of `assign` to dynamically create variables on the fly usually indicates the opportunity to use a named list.

Specifically, gather your items in *GDPn_list* and *GDP_list* and then use `Map` (the non-simplified wrapper to `mapply`) to iterate elementwise between both equal-length lists that calls the division function `/`. Then name the list with `setNames()`. Below demonstrates with random data but for you as the OP can use commented out lines to build list.

**Original Data**

```
cats <- c("GDP","CONS","GOV","INV","EX","IM")

set.seed(9272018)
GDPn_list <- setNames(replicate(6, runif(50)*120, simplify=FALSE), paste0(cats, "n"))
# GDPn_list <- list(GDPn, CONSn, GOVn, INVn, EXn, IMn)

str(GDPn_list)
# List of 6
#  $ GDPn : num [1:50] 52.4 31.9 10.6 118.4 66 ...
#  $ CONSn: num [1:50] 18.27 22.3 95.13 87.44 9.79 ...
#  $ GOVn : num [1:50] 48.83 69.73 113.61 35.53 1.21 ...
#  $ INVn : num [1:50] 51.9 96.9 28.2 67.2 19 ...
#  $ EXn  : num [1:50] 28.3 94.3 42.3 65.5 83.6 ...
#  $ IMn  : num [1:50] 109.3 26.6 60.2 78.2 55.5 ...

GDP_list <- setNames(replicate(6, runif(50)*100, simplify=FALSE), cats)
# GDPn_list <- list(GDP, CONS, GOV, INV, EX, IM)

str(GDP_list)    
# List of 6
#  $ GDP : num [1:50] 51.1 65.9 41.5 24.5 87.3 ...
#  $ CONS: num [1:50] 47.66 77.32 46.97 48.61 2.98 ...
#  $ GOV : num [1:50] 32.6 70.3 21.5 73.4 97.8 ...
#  $ INV : num [1:50] 80.7 16.8 57.4 80.7 12.1 ...
#  $ EX  : num [1:50] 38.1 78.1 40.6 62.8 61.9 ...
#  $ IM  : num [1:50] 39.8 84.8 11.4 39.7 14.7 ...
```

**New Data**

```
GDPp_list <- setNames(Map(`/`, GDPn_list, GDP_list), paste0(cats, "p"))

str(GDPp_list)    
# List of 6
#  $ GDPp : num [1:50] 1.025 0.484 0.256 4.835 0.756 ...
#  $ CONSp: num [1:50] 0.383 0.288 2.025 1.799 3.286 ...
#  $ GOVp : num [1:50] 1.4969 0.9921 5.2891 0.4844 0.0124 ...
#  $ INVp : num [1:50] 0.644 5.775 0.491 0.832 1.578 ...
#  $ EXp  : num [1:50] 0.744 1.207 1.043 1.043 1.352 ...
#  $ IMp  : num [1:50] 2.747 0.314 5.293 1.971 3.783 ...
```

And you still can reference your underlying numeric vectors via names or index numbers without losing any functionality or data:

```
GDPp_list$GDPp
GDPp_list$CONSp
GDPp_list$GOVp
...

GDPp_list[[1]]
GDPp_list[[2]]
GDPp_list[[3]]
...
```

---

And if equal-length vectors, build a matrix from your lists! This time using `mapply`:

```
GDPp_matrix <- mapply(`/`, GDPn_list, GDP_list)
colnames(GDPp_matrix) <- paste0(cats, "p")

head(GDPp_matrix)

#           GDPp      CONSp       GOVp       INVp       EXp      IMp
# [1,] 1.0252871  0.3832836 1.49687150  0.6436575 0.7441159 2.746551
# [2,] 0.4835700  0.2884577 0.99208666  5.7753575 1.2067694 0.314102
# [3,] 0.2562130  2.0251752 5.28913247  0.4910816 1.0429316 5.292843
# [4,] 4.8345697  1.7987625 0.48436284  0.8322211 1.0431301 1.970523
# [5,] 0.7563794  3.2859395 0.01236608  1.5781949 1.3518592 3.783420
# [6,] 0.1515318 10.9332338 1.10608066 13.7953500 0.7211371 1.918249
```