# How to generate data frame variable name on the fly and address existing data frame variable with it?

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I want to do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("v1"=c(1,2,3), "v2"=c(1,2,3), "v3"=c(1,2,3), "v4"=c(1,2,3))

a <- 2

paste0("df$v", a)
get(paste0("df$v", a))
mget(paste0("df$v", a))
```

The output should be `df$v2` content printed in console.

**Question:** The main reason I am doing this is that I want to address the data frame variable with variable name that is generated on the fly. I do not want to generate new variable name, I only want to generate variable name to existing one that can be used for addressing it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: use `[[` instead of `$`, e.g. `df[[paste0("v",a)]]`.

`get()` is not generally recommended, but if you need to use it, you'll have to do this in two steps:

```
get("df")[[paste0("v",a)]]
```

(as @RonakShah suggests, it would be more idiomatic to assume you know that you're going to look in `df` and use `df[[paste0("v",a)]]`)

If you insist on using `$`, you can use `eval(parse(.))`:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("df$v",a)))
```

Comment: If I need to cheese between `get("df")[[paste0("v",a)]]` and `eval(parse(text=paste0("df$v",a)))`, which one did you recommend and why?

Comment: `get()` is definitely better (or at least less worse) than `eval(parse(...))`.  `eval(parse(...))` is more sensitive to the environment it's evaluated in, generally less robust

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval, parse(` here

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("df$v", a)))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

However, I think it is not a good way to access the variable. Instead of generating `df$v2` on the fly can you generate only `v2` on the fly so that you can do

```
df[[paste0("v", a)]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: `[[` is better aligned with `$` than `[ , .]`