# change name in variables R whit for

Tags: r, static

I'm trying to create variables to use, for each variable it's called,
M000
M001
M002
M003

Example

```
c.n_vars <- nrow(comb)
for (i in 1:c.n_vars)
{
paste("M",comb[i,1],comb[i,2],comb[i,3]) = Arima(y,order=c(arima[1,1],arima[2,1],arima[3,1]),seasonal=list(order=c(comb[i,1],comb[i,2],comb[i,3]),period=12))
}
```

where comb is all combinations

```
a <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
b <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
c <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
comb <- expand.grid(a, b,c)



row parameter1 parameter2 parameter3
1     0           0          0
2     1           0          0
3     2           0          0
4     3           0          0
5     4           0          0
6     0           1          0
7     1           1          0
8     2           1          0
9     3           1          0
10    4           1          0
11    0           2          0
12    1           2          0
13    2           2          0
14    3           2          0
15    4           2          0
```

and arima is

```
arima <- data.frame(c(2,1,4))

row parameters
1       2
2       1
3       4
```

i am trying to create

```
c.n_vars <- nrow(comb)
for (i in 1:c.n_vars)
{
paste("M",comb[i,1],comb[i,2],comb[i,3]) = Arima(y,order=c(arima[1,1],arima[2,1],arima[3,1]),seasonal=list(order=c(comb[i,1],comb[i,2],comb[i,3]),period=12))
}
```

this code must return

```
    for i = 1

    M000 = arima model saved in that variable

    for i = 2

    M100 = arima model saved in that variable

    for i = 3

    M200 = arima model saved in that variable
.
.
.
.
.
for i = 15

  M420 = arima model saved in that variable
```

and the following error appears

```
Error in paste("M", comb[i, 1], comb[i, 2], comb[i, 3]) = Arima(y, order = c(arima[1,  :  
     assignment target expands an object out of language
```

I need that each iteration of the variable 'i' be saved in a different variable

Is there any solution? or another way to do it

Comment: Ok first things first please provide some sample data

Comment: What's the question exactly? Just how to change variable names? Any reason why `names(foo) <- c("blah", "blah2")` doesn't work? I don't get what the rest of the code has to do with that, or the error message

Comment: You cannot assign to `paste()`. Have a look at this : [Create a variable name with “paste” in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510966/create-a-variable-name-with-paste-in-r)

Comment: i use assign 
and throw the following error 
 Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code is still incomplete. I was not able to run it. For example y is missing.

As Base_R_Best_R pointed out, you cannot use paste to create variables like that. You can use the following pattern instead. Also note that I replaced paste() with paste0() to avoid spaces in the names:

```
result = list()
for (i in 1:c.n_vars)
{
  result[[paste0("M",comb[i,1],comb[i,2],comb[i,3])]] = Arima(y,order=c(arima[1,1],arima[2,1],arima[3,1]),seasonal=list(order=c(comb[i,1],comb[i,2],comb[i,3]),period=12))
}
```

Access your variables like this:

```
result$M100
```