# For Loop Dynamic Variable

Tags: r

This is kind of what I was thinking but not sure how to do it correctly

```
for (i in seq(0,180,by=5)){
    nam <- paste("data", i, sep = "")
    nam <- subset(data,Angle==i)
}
```

Essentially want it to be the equivalent of the code below but for all values from 0 to 180 in increments of 5

```
data0 <- subset(data,Angle==0)
data90 <- subset(data,Angle==90)
data180 <- subset(data,Angle==180)
```

Comment: What are the values in `Angle` ? Perhaps, a simpler way is `list_data <- split(data, data$Angle)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

take a look at `asign` and [Create a variable name with "paste" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510966/create-a-variable-name-with-paste-in-r)

For your case it will be something like the following, though `subset` seems like a personal defined function:

```
for (i in seq(0,180,by=5)){
    assign(paste("data", i, sep = ""),subset(data,Angle==i))
}
```